# No Credentials for Amplify GraphQL in NextJs 14 App Router SSR route.ts + No Cookies

Tags: next.js, graphql, stripe-payments, aws-amplify

I'm setting up a route.ts to handle a Stripe webhook. I need to make a graphql request upon success to update dynamodb via Amplify / AppSync.

This is using the new NextJs 14 app router. SSR seems to be that well documented with Amplify.

I always get the error "No Credentials" on the createTransaction graphql request. The cookies I'm passing into nextServerContext are always empty - it seems like this is the problem.

I'm running locally.

I've tried:

- this in layout.tsx

```js
Amplify.configure(amplifyConfig, {
  ssr: true // required when using Amplify with Next.js - it make Amplify store the auth tokens in cookies
});
```

Also tried upgrading node to 20.11.0
Tried using reqResBasedClient and runWithAmplifyServerContext

```js
// This doesn't work because "req" is from NextRequest not the old NextApiRequest 
        const result = await runWithAmplifyServerContext({
           nextServerContext: { req },
           operation: async (contextSpec) => {
             const request = await reqResBasedClient.graphql(contextSpec, {
               query: createTransaction,
                     variables: {
                       transaction: transactionInput
                     },
             });
    
             return request.data.createTransaction.paymentIntentId;
           }
         });
```

Any help greatly appreciated! How is anyone using Amplify with App Router? I have a feeling Amplify should be updating the cookies with the current auth credentials but the cookies in route.ts are all empty/null.

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import Stripe from 'stripe';
import { createTransaction } from '../../../graphql/mutations';
import { TransactionInput } from '../../../graphql/API';

import { cookieBasedClient } from '../../../utils/amplifyServerUtils';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'; // this is supposed to be for ssr but it's always null 


const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY!, {
  // @ts-ignore
  apiVersion: '2022-11-15',
});

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: 'Method not allowed' }), {
      status: 405,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
  }

  // Cookie debug
  const rawCookies = req.headers.get('cookie');
  console.log('Raw Cookie String:', rawCookies);

  const otherRawCookies = req.cookies.getAll();
  console.log('Other Raw Cookies:', otherRawCookies);

  console.log('cookies from next header = ', cookies().getAll());


  const sig = req.headers.get('stripe-signature');
  let event;

  try {
    const body = await readRawBody(req);
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, sig!, process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET!);
  } catch (err: any) {
    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: `Webhook Error: ${err.message}` }), {
      status: 400,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
  }

  switch (event.type) {
    case 'charge.succeeded':
      console.log('Handling charge.succeeded');
      break;
    case 'payment_intent.created':
      console.log('Handling payment_intent.created');
      break;
    case 'payment_intent.canceled':
      console.log('Handling payment_intent.canceled');
      break;
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
      console.log('Handling payment_intent.succeeded');

      const paymentIntentSucceeded = event.data.object as Stripe.PaymentIntent;

      console.log('paymentIntentSucceeded = ', paymentIntentSucceeded);

      const transactionInput: TransactionInput = {
        transactionId: paymentIntentSucceeded.id,
        userId: '1234', // TODO: get this
        amount: paymentIntentSucceeded.amount, 
        currency: paymentIntentSucceeded.currency,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        status: paymentIntentSucceeded.status, 
        paymentIntentId: paymentIntentSucceeded.id, 
        priceId: 'priceId', // TODO: set this 
      };
      
      try {
        // This doesn't work. Fails with "No Credentials" error 
        const result = await cookieBasedClient.graphql({
          query: createTransaction,
                    variables: {
                      transaction: transactionInput
                    },
        })


        console.log("createTransaction result transactionId = ", result.data.createTransaction?.transactionId);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("createTransaction failed with error: ", error);
    }
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Unhandled Stripe webhook event type:', event.type);
      break;
  }

  return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ received: true }), {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });
}

// Helper function to read raw request body
async function readRawBody(req: NextRequest): Promise<string> {
  if (!req.body) {
    throw new Error("Request body is null");
  }

  const reader = req.body.getReader();
  let receivedValue = '';
  let done = false;

  while (!done) {
    const { value, done: readerDone } = await reader.read();
    done = readerDone;
    if (value) {
      receivedValue += new TextDecoder().decode(value, { stream: true });
    }
  }

  return receivedValue;
}
```

Comment: For reference, your issue: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/12867

Answer (score 0):

The issue [`aws-amplify/amplify-js #12867`](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/12867) now has [a conclusion](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/12867#issuecomment-1936149688):

> We have a tagged release that you can use to test whether it resolves your issue. Please note these are not meant for production, only for verification.
>
> Install these packages and versions in your project and let us know if it fixes the issue for you.
>
> ```bash
> npm i aws-amplify@6.0.16-iam-auth-server.ebba1a4.0 @aws-amplify/adapter-nextjs@1.0.16-
> iam-auth-server.ebba1a4.0
> ```

And it seems to work:

```js
const client = generateServerClientUsingCookies({
  config: config,
  cookies,
  // authMode: "iam", Default is configured to IAM
});

const mutationTest = await client.graphql({
  query: mutations.createTodo,
  variables: {
    input: {
      content: "Content",
    },
  },
  // authMode: "iam", Default is configured to IAM
});

const queryTest = await client.graphql({
    query: queries.listTodo,
    variables: {},
    // authMode: "iam", Default is configured to IAM
  });
```

---

Update, that fix is now available in [`aws-amplify@v6.0.17`](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/releases/tag/aws-amplify%406.0.17).